# What is the most Pythonic way to shorten this proportioning method?

Tags: python

I'm looking for a way for shorten `find_equivalent()` proportioning method in most Pythonic way.

if `y` number is not in range `0 - 2000` method should return `0`. Otherwise, method should find the range of the `y` and return the equal number to the range.

```
def find_equivalent(y):
    if y <= 0 or y > 2000:
        return 0
    elif 0 < y <= 100:
        if y in range(1, 34):
            return 18
        if y in range(34, 67):
            return 17
        if y in range(67, 101):
            return 16
    elif 100 < y <= 200:
        if y in range(101, 134):
            return 15
        if y in range(134, 167):
            return 14
        if y in range(167, 201):
            return 13
    elif 200 < y <= 500:
        if y in range(201, 301):
            return 12
        if y in range(301, 401):
            return 11
        if y in range(401, 501):
            return 10
    elif 500 < y <= 1000:
        if y in range(501, 667):
            return 9
        if y in range(667, 834):
            return 8
        if y in range(834, 1001):
            return 7
    elif 1000 < y <= 2000:
        if y in range(1001, 1334):
            return 6
        if y in range(1334, 1667):
            return 5
        if y in range(1667, 2001):
            return 4
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: I'm going to assume you've made a typo and it should  be `elif 500 < y <= 1000` such that your last conditional has a purpose?

Comment: Why do you have all those `elif` tests when you then further test `y` *again*? You may as well make all those `if y in range(...)` tests the top level (using `elif` to short circuit)

Comment: @Mitch you are right. I corrected the typo. Thanks.

Comment: You probably can *calculate* the return value, rather than use ranges.

Comment: @MartijnPieters wouldnt `y in range(...)` fail if `y = 3.3` for example?

Comment: @RedX: Who says `y` is a float?

Comment: @MartijnPieters You are probably right. I missed the fact that he is already using the range approach.

Comment: "y" may in float type

Comment: I have written in this way for easier understanding of the problem.

Comment: @SencerH. There is a distinction between writing a solution in an easy way to understand and writing a bad solution. You should try and think about a direct mathematical formulation. Try to figure out how to return the correct number for the ranges for 4, then 5. From there, extending the formula should be trivial.

Comment: @SencerH.: in which case your `y in range(...)` tests will all fail unless `y` is a whole number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just *calculate* your numbers:

```
if 0 < y <= 200:
   return 18 - ((y - 1) // 33)
elif 200 < y <= 500:
   return 12 - ((y - 201) // 100)
elif 500 < y <= 1000:
   return 9 - ((y - 501) // 667))
elif 1000 < y <= 2000:
   return 6 - ((y - 501) // 1333)
return 0
```

and even those boundary values can be calculated; they are based on the range divided by 3.

You could put most of this into a list and use bisection to find the right boundaries:

```
from bisect import bisect_left

boundaries = [0, 100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000]

def find_equivalent(y):
    if not 0 < y <= 2000:
        return 0

    index = bisect_left(boundaries, y)
    stepsize = (boundaries[index] - boundaries[index - 1]) // 3
    return 21 - (index * 3) - ((y - boundaries[index - 1] - 1) // stepsize)
```

or pre-calculate the smaller range boundaries, but still use bisection:

```
boundaries = [0, 100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000]
precise_boundaries = [
    upper - ((upper - boundaries[i]) // 3 * step)
    for i, upper in enumerate(boundaries[1:])
    for step in range(2, -1, -1)]

def find_equivalent(y):
    if not 0 < y <= 2000:
        return 0
    return 18 - bisect_left(precise_boundaries, y)
```

Comment: Using *bisect* is good solution for *number*. What if I'm going to use **float**?

Comment: @SencerH.: bisection works fine with floating point numbers, unlike your `y in range(...)` tests.

Comment: I set the boundaries as `[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 10.0, 20.0]`, but when I give a float number in range between *0.1* and *1.9* to method, python gives a  **ZeroDivisionError: float divmod()** error on `return 21 - (index * 3) - ((y - boundaries[index - 1] - 1) // stepsize)` line because of the `stepsize` is calculated as *0* (zero). How sould I solve this problem?

Comment: @SencerH.: `//` is *floor division*, and always produces an integer. Use `/` (true division) instead if you need to produce floating-point fractional steps.

Comment: I also wondering the numbers 21 and 18 on return lines. Where are they came from?

EDIT: I got it. Sorry for the dummy question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use two lists, one containing the values for the range and the other containing the return values, i.e.

```
rangelist = [0, 1, 34, 67, 100 (etc)]
returnlist = [18, 17, 16 (etc)]
```

Then, you can find the entry of `rangelist` closest to your `y` and pick the matching item from `returnlist`.